# Why does my nads tickle when going over bumps?

Tags: testicles

I always wondered when a kid and now. To be quite frank I actually don't even want to post question like this.

But when I ever I go on some rides (drop fast) or bumps fast my nads/balls tickle. Could someone explain why that is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always wondered this myself and now my seven year old always ask this when in the back of the car. I came across this:

> Normally, all the parts of your body are pushing on each other because of the constant force of gravity. But in the "free-fall" state of plummeting down a hill, there is hardly any net force acting on you. In this case, the various pieces of your body are not pushing on each other as much. They are all, essentially, weightless, each falling individually inside your body. This is what gives you that unique sinking feeling in your stomach -- your stomach is suddenly very light because there is less force pushing on it. The same thing happens when you drive down a dip in the road in your car or descend in an elevator moving at high speed.

So in effect your "nads" are weightless and I guess that's why you get the sensation.

Comment: That's what I thought. Very interesting thank you.

Comment: That's a legitimate answer